# How to use base Tailwind CSS colors along with daisyUI theme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, daisyui

I'm using Tailwind CSS along with daisyUI for a NextJS project. I have my `tailwind.config.js` file set up as:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
/* eslint-env node */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
        './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
        'node_modules/daisyui/dist/**/*.js',
        'node_modules/react-daisyui/dist/**/*.js',
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
        fontFamily: {
            sans: ['Roboto', 'sans-serif'],
        },
    },
    daisyui: {
        themes: [
            {
                mytheme: {
                    primary: '#8855B4',
                    secondary: '#00C9AF',
                    accent: '#f3d0f5',
                    neutral: '#373f4a',
                    'base-100': '#FFFFFF',
                    info: '#3ABFF8',
                    success: '#36D399',
                    warning: '#FBBD23',
                    error: '#F87272',
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [require('daisyui')],
}
```

When I try to use a color defined within my daisyUI theme, it works fine:

```
<h1 className="text-3xl font-bold text-accent">Your Trips</h1>
```

[image]

But when I use a color defined in base tailwind, it does not work.

```
<h1 className="text-3xl font-bold text-red-400">Your Trips</h1>
```

[image]

As you can see, the text is black instead of red-400.

It seems like daisyUI is overriding my access to Tailwind colors? How can I use the base tailwind colors along with a daisyUI theme?

Comment: does other classes like `text-2xl` or `border` apply ? Or is it just colors ?

Comment: @Johan seems to be just the color, if I change a `text-sm` to `text-2xl` it applies.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may have overridden the default theme with the daisyui theme as opposed to extending the default theme.

You should be able to correct this by moving your theme components to the extend section in your tailwind.config.js.

[Extending the default theme](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#extending-the-default-theme)

Comment: According to https://daisyui.com/docs/themes/, it has to go within the daisyui block.

Comment: Any ideas on how to use both the daisyUI theme, while having access to tailwind colors?

Comment: I'm afraid not.  Although, on the off chance it helps, using your tailwind.config.js in a new next.js project; I am unable to replicate the issue: the text-red-400 and text-accent are both being applied.

Comment: Did you install daisyUI as well?

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue, I solved it with putting my additional styles to 'extend' object of tailwind. In your version, you can do it as putting your fontFamily to there. **But dont touch daisyUI object**, it should be in the same place.
Like this:
https://daisyui.com/docs/themes/#-4